# Square shadows in rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm making a cushion and when I render it, there are square shadows. Is this because I didn't subdivide surface enough? Or did I touch something wrong? In Edit mode, it looks already to have a lot of faces. Is there way to smooth the shadow?

I'm not using lamp object but world with Pro lighting Skies add-on.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd guess you don't have it subdivided enough. Is there anyway you can upload your blend file?

Comment: hmmmm.... that is weird not sure why it would be doing that.  Maybe try turning off Pro lighting skies and use an HDRI https://hdrihaven.com/  and see if Pro Lighting is causing the problem. Also maybe select all and recalculate normals (just in case).

Comment: @haruka.k Maybe try it in Cycles render...

Comment: I tried to turn off Pro lighting Skies now the shadow looks ok. So probably it was that. Perhaps because I'm using uni machine... so they don't allow to put add-on? I'm using Cycles render, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Afaik Pro Lighting skies work only with Cycles.. but your question is tagged as "blender-render". It would be good to edit it to make it clear as to what engine is used.

Comment: Oh I didn't know there was the cycle tag! I thought that was the only tag I could use regarding to Blender since I search Blender and it is only choice. Thank you for teaching me, now I changed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I turned off the Pro Lighting add-on. I suppose because the uni machine I'm using doesn't allow to use or something... though it looked installed. Thank you for the help!